# list group item text is cropped in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3.

I have a list-group-item, but when the width causes the text to pop to the next line, text is cropped, as shown in the picture, on the second line.
[image: cropped-text]
What can I do?

This is my code:

```
<div class="list-group-item getItemActivityHistory" item_id="6">        
            <div class="text-info"><b>חשמל</b>
                <span class="pull-right">נוצל החודש: 
                <span>
                    666
                </span></span>
            </div>
            <div>יתרת תקציב: <span class="leftToRight">לא הוגדר</span>
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        התחייבויות עתידיות: 100
                    </span>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` solved the issue.

But I realy do not understand why. "hidden"' should do the opposite.

???